# Как заменить все символы в строке кроме первого и последнего?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть фраза - `"ПРЫГНИСЮДА"`. Как написать запрос, чтобы выдавалось `П********А`?

Писал через:

```
regexp_replace('ПРЫГНИСЮДА', '.' , '*', 2)
```

Но не могу понять, как написать на регулярке до последнего символа в строке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT regexp_replace( 'hellllow', '(^\D{1})(.*)(\D{1}$)', '\1**********\3' ) example FROM dual;`

Результат: h**********w

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное !
Единственное, не могли бы уточнить значению данного выражения  '\1**********\3' ?

Comment: '\1**********\3'  шаблон по которому будет отображаться строка, тоесть первая буква, 10 звезд, последняя буква

Answer (score 2):

Зачем тут регулярные выражения? Взять первый символ, последний символ, между ними подсчитаное (или заданное) кол-во звёздочек, готово:

```
select 
    substr (str, 1, 1)||rpad ('*', length (str)-2, '*')||substr (str, -1, 1) res 
from t1
```

Если всё таки регулярным выражением, то так:

```
select 
    regexp_replace (str, '.*(.$)', rpad ('*', length (str)-2, '*')||'\1', 2) res 
from t1
```

Запросы выше можно попробовать на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2b17894e3925ec3cba26d8a6ff8d699f), оба вернут ожидаемый результат:

```
RES
----------------
1*3
a****f
#******/
```